# TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 with Google APIs

Tags: c#, ssl, google-analytics

I have been using the Google .NET APIs in reporting applications for years; no problem.

Now my organization is enforcing servers use only TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 without exception, and that has broken the applications; the error messages say that the client and server do not share a common algorithm.

Is there any possibility for these libraries to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2?  Is there any setting that the Google Account administrator can change?

Thanks